# Create a regex for removing special character in url

Tags: regex

I am using the below two urls and I wanted to remove data before :// tag given in the url I also want that :// should be removed using regex

```
"javascript:void window.open('http://media.corporate-ir.net/media_files/irol/global_html/plugin_help.htm', '', 'status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=450,height=300')
```

Output- media.corporate-ir.net/media_files/irol/global_html/plugin_help.htm', '', 'status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width=450,height=300'

```
http://www.corporate-ir.net/media_files/priv/CCBN/event_help/icons/md_pdf.gif
```

Output- www.corporate-ir.net/media_files/priv/CCBN/event_help/icons/md_pdf.gif

The regex I am using is below

```
^[^://]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex: `^[^://]*` is faulty since there are no groups inside `[` and `]` (character class).

To replace use this regex for search:

```
^.*?:\/\/
```

And replace by:

```
""
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM4gR1/3)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: @Anoop i have seen at least 4 to 5 questions of yours where you do not accept an answer and move on.Please accept so that others may benefit from it.